# MySql: How to select all joined rows between two tables and all rows from first that satisfy condition using single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables.

Lets say table p and table q. Here is what I do:

```
select p.*, q.* 
from p inner join q on p.field = q.field 
where q.col = 'someValue';
```

Suppose that resultset is something like this:

```
p.field q.field ....
   5       5      ...
   6       6      ...
   12      12       ..
   55      55       ....
   3       3      ...
```

Now I want to select these rows and  that using single query:

```
select p.*  
from p where p.sat = 'value'
```

resultset:

```
p.field  ....
   44     ...
   93        ...
   13      ..
   8      ....
   55      ...
```

I don't want to use `union` or subqueries.

However I want to unite/merge these rows in the following (example) resultset:

```
p.field q.field ....
   5       5      ...
   6       6      ...
   12      12       ..
   55      55       ....
   44      null      ...
   93      null      ...
   13      null       ..
   8       null       ....
```

I have to join the two result sets to third table and order by a field in the third one (if it does matter).

Comment: Maybe I should try union

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  p1.*, 
  q.* ,
  p2.* -- Note that you might need to change the columns' names 
       -- with different aliases than those selected from p1.*
FROM p       AS p1
INNER JOIN q        ON p.field = q.field 
INNER JOIN p AS p2  ON p.field = p2.field 
                   AND p2.sat = 'value'
WHERE q.col = 'someValue'
-- ORDER BY ...;
```

---

I think you have to use `UNION` for this like so:

```
SELECT
  p.field field1,
  q.field field2
FROM p
INNER JOIN q  ON p.field = q.field
UNION ALL
SELECT p.field, NULL
FROM p
WHERE sat = 'value';
```

This will give you:

```
| FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
-------------------
|      5 |      5 |
|      6 |      6 |
|     12 |     12 |
|     55 |     55 |
|      3 |      3 |
|     55 |     55 |
|     44 | (null) |
|     93 | (null) |
|     13 | (null) |
|      8 | (null) |
|     55 | (null) |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b154/5)

Comment: excuse me for not answering till now but I want to unite the results and not intersect them :)

Comment: @alexanderg - Its OK, take your time. What do you mean? Can you please edit your question and  post some sample data of these two tables `p` and `q` with the desired result set that you are looking for from those two tables. this can be very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Ive done some edit. hope it helps :) What I want is something like inner join and left join with different conditions but I cant figure it out.

Comment: @alexanderg - I don't know really how to do this using only joins, but you can do this using union, see my edit.

Comment: Ill use do it with union. I thought it is possible using only joins... coalesce maybe :) but thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: @alexanderg - How about [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b154/7), this is my attempt.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows where `p.sat = 'value'` as well as the ones that satisfy the join and condition on q.  This is most easily expressed as a `left outer join`:

```
select p.*, q.* 
from p left outer join
     q
     on p.field = q.field 
where p.sat = 'value' or q.col = 'someValue'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work but try this.

`SELECT p.*, q.* FROM p, q WHERE (p.field = q.field AND q.col = 'someValue') OR (q.sat = 'value')`